# How to use simple (basic) filters in mantisBT?

Tags: mantis

I have recently setup a mantisBT (mantis Bug Tracker) site. I am able to create and manage issues. I want to apply simple filter, such as Resolution = reopened or status = closed,  on the View Issues page. I could not accomplish this and could not find any documentation on how to use fitlers.

Could someone guide me how to use filters or point me to the corresponding documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the **View Issues** link on the main menu, click on the + icon on the left hand side of **Search** and you can see the filters.

Following screenshot explains the rest of the stuff
[image: Screenshot of Mantis Filter]

Comment: Thanks. After seeing your screen shot, I figured out that I need to click on the corresponding links (Status:, Assigned To:, Severity:, etc.) to get the filtering options.